# Node package seems to not work locally unless installed globally

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm new to using Node and npm and have been working on integrating a node package with my js code. If I install the package with npm globally, then everything works. If I use it locally with package.json or from the source code and using:
`file:/home/user/......`
I get the same error as just using the npm package via package.json.

package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/evm

Error:

```
EVM.node.js:1
module.exports=function(e){var d={};function t(a){if(d[a])return d[a].exports;var s=d[a]={i:a,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[a].call(s.exports,s,s.exports,t),s.l=!0,s.exports}return t.m=e,t.c=d,t.d=function(e,d,a){t.o(e,d)||Object.defineProperty(e,d,{enumerable:!0,get:a})},t.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},t.t=function(e,d){if(1&d&&(e=t(e)),8&d)return e;if(4&d&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var a=Object.create(null);if(t.r(a),Object.defineProperty(a,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&d&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var s in e)t.d(a,s,function(d){return e[d]}.bind(null,s));return a},t.n=function(e){var d=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return t.d(d,"a",d),d},t.o=function(e,d){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,d)},t.p="",t(t.s=15)}([function(e,d,t){"use strict";Object.d

TypeError: e.replace is not a function
```

Any help is much appreciated. 
npm version = 6.9.0
Node version = v10.16.3

Comment: For us to help here, we will need to see actual code and the exact errors when things don't work.  And, please tell us which package it is.  This question is entirely abstract.  Packages work when installed locally if you do it correctly.  You need to make this question specific to your exact code and your exact situation.  Plus, I have no idea what `file:/home/user/......` is or means or what it has to do with the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 updated with info above

Comment: If `e.replace` is not a function, then it could be because the caller is not passing a string when calling the function or not passing some proper argument that is used later in the code.  Is that your code calling it?  But, with minimized code all on one line, that `e` could be some other `e` in the same line.  That's a mess to debug.

Comment: @jfriend00 my code is not doing the e.replace that is from the lib/EVM.node.js after compilation of that package.

Comment: I know that.  But, it could be an error in what you're passing to something in that library.  Or what you're passing to something else that they causes it to pass the wrong thing to this library.  Or, it could be an invalid dependent library installation too.

Comment: I actually ended up resolving it, it was another dependency with that package. Thanks for the helpful comments!